# Why do other logical symbols except $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ not have corresponding meta symbols?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The symbols $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ have corresponding meta symbols $\Rightarrow$ and $\iff$. But why other symbols like $\wedge, \vee,(,), \cdots $ do not have corresponding meta symbols? Is there are something logical reason?

Comment: No reason at all; and also the "convention" about $\to$ and $\Rightarrow$ is quite arbitrary.

Comment: Personally, I cannot imagine any benefit in writing e.g. the *Deduction Theorem* in the form : $\Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash A \to B$ instead of : $\text {if } \Gamma \cup \{ A \} \vdash B, \text { then } \Gamma \vdash A \to B$.

Comment: As the meta language equivalent of $\land$, sometimes & is used, for $\lor$ rarely a |. "For all" can be abbreviated as "f.a." and "there exists" as "ex". rather than using the respective object language quantifiers. That these abbreviations are shorter than the full English expressions is the reason why $\Rightarrow$ is often preferred over "If ... then ...".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. I think so too.

Answer (score 2):

The $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ assert important logical relationships:

$\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ is a meta-logical assertion stating that the expression $\psi$ is a logical consequence of $\varphi$

$\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$ asserts that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent

Clearly we cannot use $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ for these; those are mere truth-functional operators as part of the logic language itself; they don't assert any meta-logical relationship.

But what would be the role of a meta-logical symbol for 'and' or 'or'? What *relationship* would it express, or what *claim* would it make? In fact, if I say: "Sentence $\varphi$ AND sentence $\psi$", I am not even making a claim about $\varphi$ and $\psi$ at all, unlike $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ and $\varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi$

Comment: There is also such a close connection between the informal 'and' and the formal 'and' that there's no confusion to clear up by using different symbols. In the case logical implication $\Rightarrow$ vs. material implication $\to$ there is a genuine difference that can lead to confusion, particularly if we work in logics that don't have a version of the deduction theorem.

Comment: Are you "equating" $\Rightarrow$ with [$\vDash$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Proofs_and_models) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Pretty much, at least in the sense that both express a notion of logical consequence ... the difference I make is that I use $\Rightarrow$ for single statements, i.e. $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$ iff it is impossible for statement $\varphi$ to be True and statement $\psi$ to be False, whereas I use $\vDash$ when dealing with sets of statements: $\Gamma \vDash \psi$ iff it is impossible for all statements in the set of statements $\Gamma$ to be True and the statement $\psi$ to be False.

Comment: @ Bram 28 - Could not a metalogical version of  ' w ' ( XOR) expres the relation of contradiction between two sentences?

Comment: @RayLittleRock Hmm, interesting idea. To be exact, the metalogical XOR could express the relation of those two sentences being contradictories (always opposing truth-values) ... and a metalogical NAND could express the relationship of them being contraries (cannot both be true).

Comment: @Bram 28  I asked a question in this direction here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170831/is-the-relation-of-contradiction-between-sentences-expressible-in-first-order-lo