# In which language can one EXPRESS the fact that two sentences are contradictory ? is meta-language required?

Tags: logic

[ Edited: title modified]

Remark.- My question is not :  is it possible to produce a contradictory formula in the language of first order logic. ( I actually can produce such a formula: for ex. the formula P & ~ P ) . My question is rather : " **is it possible to say, in the language itself , that a formula is contradictory , or to say that the contradiction relation holds between two formulas.**

---

To express the idea that sentence A and sentence B contradict each  another, is it sufficient to say that :

```
                       (A w B)    [ with ' w ' meaning : exclusive OR] ?
```

or does one have to translate it as :

```
                    " necessarily   (A w B)    " ,
```

or, maybe as,

```
           " (A w B) is valid, true in all possible interpretations"
```

in which case the " contradiction " relation would not be expressible in the language of first order logic.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I cannot understand your concern... $A$ and $\lnot A$ obviously contradict each other. Thus, what do you mean with "To express the idea that sentences A and B contradict each another" ? A set of sentences (formulas) is *contradictory* or unsatisfiable when it is not possible to satisfy all them together. Thus for two sentences $A$ and $B$, we may simply say that $\{ A, B \}$ is *unsatisfiable*. A simple way to express this is to use the [*falsum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)#False,_negation_and_contradiction) constant $\bot$ writing : $\{ A, B \} \vDash \bot$.

Comment: @ Mauro Allegranza My question was related to a previous one concerning  the principle of non-contradiction: does ithis principle belong to language or to meta-language? My aim was also at knowing whether there was a modal notion involved in the principle. If I understand correctly your answer, it means that the idea " A contradicts B"  has to be expressed in the metalanguage ( via the concept of logical consequence).

Comment: I'll have to edit my question. The answer given by Bram 28 made me realize that there is a difference between " A contradicts B" and " A and B are contradictory".

Comment: Maybe... in logic a *contradiction* is a sentence/ formula that is always FALSE : $P \land \lnot P$. Obviously, $P$ and $\lnot P$ contradict each other (in the "usual" sense of the word).

Comment: I totally agree that (P& ~P) is a contradiction. My question was simply whether there was a way to  say " this sentence is a contradiction" in the language itself, or whether it has to be said at the meta-level. What I understand from your answer and Bram28's is that it has to be expressed in the meta-language, or in the language of modal logic.

Comment: @ Mauro Allegranza. - As you might have noticed, I'm not totally familiar with the distinction between language and metalangage. So I'll probably ask in the future some other questions related to this topic. Those are innocent questions; they might be boring for specialists, but asking them helps me to make sure I understand things correctly. So I apologize in advance.

Comment: There is **no** way to say " this sentence is a contradiction" in the Language itself, because the Language is a formal Language and thus has no meaning if not interpreted. And the only interpretations available with prop logic are boolean *valuations*. Being a contradiction is a property of formulas of the calculus, and thus it is defined in the meta-language. But, as said above, IT IS ALREADY DEFINED in the standard treatment of prop logic and FOL : $\varphi \vDash \bot$.

Comment: Regarding "contraries" and "contradictories", thet are still alive; see [Square of opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition). The only caveat is that the Aristotelian version, when translated in current (monadic) predicate logic, has to face the issue of so-called [existential import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition#The_problem_of_existential_import). "Contraries" and "contradictories", when used following Aristotleìs approach, do **not** apply to prop logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need the 'necessary' part in there, i.e. basically what you have in the second half of your post.

To see this, consider:

$A:$ "grass is green"

$B:$ "snow is purple"

Now, in *our* world, $A$ is true and $B$ is false, and hence $A \oplus B$ is true.  But, $A$ and $B$ do not logically contradict each other. Indeed, there are other logically possible worlds where both claims are true.

One small point though: I would say that for two sentences to contradict each other it is not necessary that they have opposing truth-values (in which case we call them 'contradictories'), but it is sufficient that they cannot both be true (in which case we call them 'contraries').

For example, I would say that $P \land Q$ and $\neg P$ contradict each other ... but it would not be the case that in all interpretations, exactly one of them is true. These two sentences are indeed not contradictory, but they are contrary.

So, using modal logic, I would express the claim that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ contradict each other as:

$\square \neg (\varphi \land \psi)$

Or, if we use $\uparrow$ for the NAND:

$\square (\varphi \uparrow \psi)$

Comment: @ Bram28 - This gives a new life to the antique distinction between " contraries" and " contradictories".!  Actually, from " A and B contradict each other" I cannot infer " A and B are contradictories", I had never thought of this in this way.